# asking for permission to access text data when using MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: ios, user-permissions, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I'm using a `MFMessageComposeViewController` instance in my app. The user clicks a button and it is taken to `MFMessageComposeViewController`. The question I am asking myself is..do I need to ask user for the permission to access to text messages on phone? I really don't need that data stored in Messages App, but my app does provide a link to it.

Comment: No, you don't. But don't worry, you can't really get data from it.

Comment: ok great. Write it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not ask user for permision because **you can't access nothing from messages**. You just open a **new message sheet** and you can pre-fill it with a sender, a message, and a few images. Message does not send automatically, only user can send iy